# Summing three biggest numbers of an AbstractMap using streams

Tags: java, java-stream, max

i have a question. How can I count the three biggest maximums of this structure?

```
public static AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long> sum3max(List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long>> list){... }
```

The expected output should look something like this:

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long>> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("apple", 20L));  
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("tomato", 30L)); 
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("apple", 10L)); 
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("tomato", 20L)); 
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("tomato", 10L)); 
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("tomato", 40L));
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("apple", 60L));
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("apple", 5L));
// apple = 90 because we are counting 60+20+10 (three biggest numbers of all apples)
// tomato = 90 because 30+20+40 (three biggest numbers of all tomatos )

System.out.println(sum3max(list)); // should be   apple=90, because 'a' in apple is alphabetically smaller than 't' in tomato
```

Can you please help me? I tried sth like this, but it works just for summing all the values, not just the three biggest.

```
var map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,Collectors.summingLong(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)));
Map.Entry<String, Long> maxEntry = map.entrySet().stream()
                .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get();


        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(maxEntry.getKey(), maxEntry.getValue());
```

Comment: I don't understand what "three biggest maximums" means and how it gets you `apple=30`.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I edited the question, to be more understandable

Comment: It still says `apple=30`.

Comment: I could understand if the expected output was `apple=90`, but I can't fathom why/how it would be `apple=30`. Please carefully re-read and edit as required so your question/problem is clear.

Comment: https://ideone.com/ygPHSd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it streaming the values.
First, create a lambda as the `finisher` to sum the largest 3 values of a list. It will be used later.

**The Finisher**

- the finisher takes a list of longs and returns a long
- first sort the values in reverse order
- limit to 3 or less and map to a long
- then sum them and return the sum

```
Function<List<Long>, Long> sum =
        lst -> lst.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .limit(3).mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
```

**Streaming the Entries**

- stream the list of entries.
- group the items keyed by `fruit` and a `value list of longs`

  - the `longs` need to be extracted from their Entry via `Collectors.mapping`.
  - then using `collectingAndThen` to first collect those longs in a list
  - followed by the previously defined `finisher` to return the long sum

```
Map<String,Long> map =
        list.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toList(),
                                        sum::apply))));

 map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
apple=90
tomato=90
```

My solution permits items which have less than three numbers.  It would also be possible to filter out such lists.  I chose to allow them.